# Building signed APK of release build fails but debug succeeds. Missing class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When going to build the signed APK for my app if I select the debug build it compiles fine, but when I choose the release build it sits on

> :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease

and it says

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

as well as

> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class
>   android.arch.paging.PositionalDataSource","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

I have tried adding to my build.gradle(module)

```
dexOptions{
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
}
```

as well as adding some ignoring to the proguard.cfg

NOTE: I am using MacOS if that might have anything to do with it

Comment: Well it sounds like the cause has to do with whatever is different between you debug build and your release build? Proguard ? anything that has to do with reflection that might be the cause during compilation and build?

Comment: @FunkSoulBrother I have determined it is to do with proguard, if I remove the line "proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'" the release build works

Comment: possibly to do with gradle 3.4.0 using r8 now

Answer (score 1):

Proguard (which is turned on by default for release builds if I'm not mistaken) should be used very carefully.

ANY code that uses reflection might stop working if obfuscated so if you do want to use Proguard - you need to determine which classes are to be used with reflection and exclude (keep as is ) them.

More info here : https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I think some things must have changed now that it uses r8, I will probably just need to read up more on the topic

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same stack trace. In my case, there were missing 
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512M -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx1g"` configs in the gradle.propertis file.